# Execute SQL query on all DB's

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a SQL Server with 17 databases that have the same table structure. I want to do a count query for each of that table in each DB

```
DECLARE @command varchar(1000)

SELECT @command = 'IF ''?'' NOT IN(''master'', ''model'', ''msdb'', ''tempdb'', ''ReportServer'', ''ReportserverTempDB'') 

BEGIN 
    USE ? 
    EXEC(''SELECT COUNT(MODEL) AS rptdevicecount 
           FROM dbo.devices WHERE MODEL IS NOT NULL'') END'

EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @command
```

Now I have 2 questions:

1. how can I combine the count results? So I want to know how many devices there are in total, not per DB.
2. When running this query, I get an error

   > Msg 911, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
   >   Database 'CH' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.

I should fix this by adding `IF EXISTS`. But where do I have to put that?

Thank you!

Comment: For summing up the results I'd say do it in your program rather than with query, since all databases act independently.

Comment: 1)  I would store the results in a temp table.  2)  Why would SQL Server think that you have a db named "CH" when you don't?   Did you have one?  Do you have one that's in an unreadable state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #T1 (DBName varchar(20), Qty int)
EXECUTE master.sys.sp_msforeachdb 'USE [?]; 
IF DB_NAME() NOT IN (''master'',''model'',''msdb'',''tempdb'',''ReportServer'',''ReportServerTempDB'')
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #T1
    SELECT db_Name(), COUNT(*) FROM sys.tables
END
'
SELECT SUM(qty) FROM #T1
DROP TABLE #T1
```